# My checkbox should not repeat in an iterate loop

Tags: struts-1

I have a `<logic:iterate></logic:iterate>` loop in which I added a checkbox I want that the checkbox should not be added after every element in `<iterate>` loop.

I only want to print my:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="configureCheckBox" >Configure<br/>
```

this checkbox with only first element.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using an `s:iterator` tag (since the question is tagged as struts2), you can use the `status` attribute to check if you are printing the first element:

```
<s:iterator value="yourVar" status="cycleStatus">
    <s:if test="#cycleStatus.first">
    <input type="checkbox" id="configureCheckBox" >Configure<br/>
    </s:if>
    <%-- other code --%>
</s:iterator>
```

See also the [`s:iterator`](https://struts.apache.org/docs/iterator.html) and [`IteratorStatus`](https://struts.apache.org/maven/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/views/jsp/IteratorStatus.html) documentation.

Comment: i dont want to use <%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags" %>  any other idea for doing this

Comment: if you are using `logic:iterate`, try to use the [`indexId`](http://people.apache.org/~germuska/struts-taglib/docs/tlddoc/logic/iterate.html) property; if you are iterating with Java code inside your jsp, you could check against your loop counter.

Answer (score 0):

You can play with indexId in this case.

You can use something like

`<logic:iterate indexId="index">
    <%if (Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(index))){%>
         <input type="checkbox" id="configureCheckBox" >Configure<br/>
    <%}%>
</logic:iterate>`